# How to use NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification to check for change in iCloud on or off change?

Tags: notifications, cloudkit, account

the apple documentation says to use the NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification to sense iCloud account changes  and "When your app receives this notification, get the **new token** from the **NSURLRelationship** property. The value of that token is nil if the user has disabled iCloud. There is no userInfo dictionary."

I know how to setup my code to get notified when the NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification occurs, but I  don't understand where  to read the "NSURLRelationship" property from and then what its multiple values mean. The documentation says the following about "NSRULRelationship", that is "Constants indicating the relationship between a directory and an item."

I don't know what "relationship between a directory and an item" have anything to do with whether there was a change in the iCloud account . 
The values of NSURLRelationship are :

```
enum NSURLRelationship : Int {
case Contains
case Same
case Other
```

}

So any idea how one should these values to determine a change in iCloud account and where to read these values from?

thanks